# Was youtube-nocookie.com always serving cookies or did it start recently? Is it a scam?

Tags: cookie, youtube, privacy, gdpr, embed

I've been using Youtube embeds in [enhanced privacy mode](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en#zippy=%2Cturn-on-privacy-enhanced-mode) by

> chang[ing] the domain for the embed URL in your HTML from https://www.youtube.com to https://www.youtube-nocookie.com

I remember checking via DevTools (Application/Storage tab) that no cookie was actually set.

A customer just notified me that they did find cookies set by the domain `.youtube-nocookie.com` -- weirdly, something about "consent pending", which does not change when I click play, as other sources state.
They have also alerted me to some shenanigans in Local Storage, namely an item with the key `yt-remote-device-id`, which has a UUID and an expiration date 10 years in the future.

I have always suspected that **Enhanced Privacy Mode** is somewhat of a exaggeration, but this seems to defeat the purpose almost entirely. And it makes youtube-nocookie practically useless w.r.t. a less painful GDPR-compliant user experience.

Is this a recent change? Is there any documentation or changelog on that?

Comment: Good question! Found related answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61887699/gdpr-youtube-nocookie-embedded-urls-need-visitors-permission. Apparently you're right that "*Rather than disabling tracking, “privacyenhanced mode” seems to cover it up*"